# how to check only lines that were added since last check in bash

Tags: bash, shell, logging, error-handling, cron

I have a dilemma.
I need to check log files using bash script.
The script needs to run every 5-10 minutes (set it in crontab) and send email if there is a warning or error in logs.
But it has to check only lines that were added since last check and not go through the whole document again and again.
I don't know how to check only lines that were added since last check, or lines that were added in the last 10 minutes
Sleep won't work in my situation because the script shouldn't be running all the time it should be done once every 5-10 minutes

Comment: How big is your log file ? a few ko ? 10 Mo ? 10 Go ?

Comment: Found a solution, I just save line count in external file and then read from it. Then use tail with difference between current line count and previous line count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is not too big, you could try storing the previous number of lines of your log file in an environment variable, and compare it with the current line number. Something like the following script should work :

```
#!/bin/bash

#here, detect_errors is a placeholder name for the function you already developped
#we use only the lines we haven't seen yet in our detect_errors function
detect_errors "$(head -n $(($(wc -l log.file) - OLD_LINE_COUNT)) log.file)"

#we update the new value for the $OLD_LINE_COUNT
export OLD_LINE_COUNT="$(wc -l log.file)"
```

**DETAILED EXPLANATION**

- `head -n X myfile` : displays the first X lines of `myfile`
- `$(( ... ))` : arithmetic calculations in `bash`
- `wc -l log.file` : line count for our file
- `$OLD_LINE_COUNT` : environement variable where we store the line count of the previous iteration (equals to 0 when we first launch the script)

If the file is unchanged, `$(wc -l log.file) - OLD_LINE_COUNT` will return 0, and `head -n 0` returns empty.

If the log file is too big, `wc -l` will take a lot of time, so in this case my method wouldn't be recomended.

**EDIT:** I have not asked how your log file is incremented. If the additional lines are added AT THE END OF THE FILE, you should use `tail -n` instead of `head -n`

Comment: Thank you, I used your logic, but instead of saving it into environment variable I saved line count in external file